# Error Code: 1066. Not unique table/ali

Tags: mysql

```
select shipment_status.Sales_Order_Id,product_details.Product_Name,
shipment_status.Unit_Price,shipment_status.Status
from shipment_status,product_details
left join product_details ON 
shipment_status.Sales_Order_Id= product_details.Product_ID;
```

I am trying to perform a left join but I'm getting the error:

> Not unique table/alias.

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting from `product_details` twice:

from shipment_status,*product_details* left join *product_details*

You probably don't want the first one, because that would cause your results to become a cartesian product of the two tables, since you're not limiting on any relation between the two (as you do in the ON clause of the LEFT JOIN).

Comment: Ya, got it. Thank you so much Gerard Van Helden